# Tried to have recursive relation

Tags: oracle

I use oracle and I try to have a recursive relation

```
CREATE TABLE  "EVENT"
(
    "EVENT_ID" NUMBER(18) NOT NULL, //primary key
    "NAME" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "RELATED_EVENT_ID" NUMBER(18) NULL  //foreign key
);
```

Event 1 parent is Event 2....

When I try to create this table, I get this error.

```
ALTER TABLE  "EVENT" 
 ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_RELATED_EVENT_ID"
FOREIGN KEY ("RELATED_EVENT_ID") REFERENCES  "EVENT" ("RELATED_EVENT_ID")
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html) :

> Foreign key specifies that the values in the column must correspond to values in a
>   referenced primary key or unique key column or that they are NULL.

In your case, create `primary key` on column (`EVENT_ID`) and use it in `reference` clause as following:

```
ALTER TABLE  "EVENT" 
 ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_RELATED_EVENT_ID"
FOREIGN KEY ("RELATED_EVENT_ID") 
  REFERENCES  "EVENT" ("EVENT_ID") -- this
```

Now, use **EVENT2**'s `EVENT_ID` as `RELATED_EVENT_ID` in **EVENT1** record to make **EVENT2** as parent of **EVENT1**.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. There is no primary key constraint on this table.
2. The foreign key constraint you defined has `RELATED_EVENT_ID` referencing `RELATED_EVENT_ID`. I suspect that was just a typo.

Change your table definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT
 (EVENT_ID            NUMBER
    NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_EVENT
      PRIMARY KEY
      USING INDEX,
    NAME              VARCHAR2(20),
    RELATED_EVENT_ID  NUMBER);
```

Then add the foreign key constraint as

```
ALTER TABLE EVENT
  ADD CONSTRAINT EVENT_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (RELATED_EVENT_ID) REFERENCES EVENT(EVENT_ID);
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e50522f7c5b3c89475f62c659ae24b7)

### EDIT

Note that the better way to handle this is to use a junction table, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT_EVENT
 (EVENT_ID1    NUMBER
    CONSTRAINT EVENT_EVENT_FK1
      REFERENCES EVENT(EVENT_ID),
  EVENT_ID2    NUMBER
    CONSTRAINT EVENT_EVENT_FK2
      REFERENCES EVENT(EVENT_ID),
  CONSTRAINT PK_EVENT_EVENT
    PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_ID1, EVENT_ID2)
      USING INDEX);
```

Then you can drop the `RELATED_EVENT_ID` column from EVENT as you no longer need it.